# Check input field validity as the user types in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I want to give the user feedback on, for example (but not limited to) the validity of an email field as the user types, i.e. client-side validation.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <div :class="['input-group', validateEmail()]">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
        </div>
      <input type="text" v-model="email" placeholder="joe@example.org" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Before the user types anything, I'd like the field to be uncolored.  As she types, the outline becomes red until she has put in a properly formatted email, at which point the outline becomes green.  All other input fields should be unaffected by this. Another example might be the password field that becomes green as the requirements/constraints are met.

In bootstrap 3 it was pretty simple to add a `has-error` or `has-success` class to an input field via a javascript method per this example https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/MmpBjV.

However, it seems that in bootstrap-4 with the shift to HTML5 pseudo-classes `:is-valid` and `:is-invalid` it has become a lot more complicated with the necessity to add `was-validated` or `needs-validation` to the form tag, and the difficulty in setting those pseudo-classes on a single field via javascript.  Am I missing something?  Is there a simple way to replicate the bootstrap-3 functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4, you can use `.is-invalid` and `.is-valid` classes on `.form-control` to manually indicate the form fields validity

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#server-side

### **Codepen demo**

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I was applying the validator to the `input-group` and not the `input`, which works with bootstrap 3 but not with the pseudo-classes.